# Disable Map on Mobile Phones-Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile

How can I disable the map on mobile phones in wordpress?

I tried to add this code to  ./design/css/responsive.css:

```
@media(max-width: 497px){
div#directory-main-bar { display: none;}
}
```

But the map is still displayed.

Comment: What map? Is a google/bing map? An image you have on a page/footer/header?

Comment: I'm using this directory theme: http://preview.ait-themes.com/index.php?bartype=desktop&theme=directory I don't know what is the map they use.

Comment: Did you try adding that code to the style.css file?

Comment: It has to be added to responsive.css

Answer (score 0):

Adding `!important;` after display:none; should work.

```
@media(max-width: 497px)
{
    div#directory-main-bar 
    { 
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

The reason your style wasn't working is because of this in the style.css

```
#directory-main-bar 
{
    max-height: 380px !important;
}
```

Comment: @Rori, in that case without a link to the website or a jsfiddle showing this problem, it will be hard to help.